# Много таблиц, плохо или хорошо?

Tags: mysql

Делаю интернет магазин и собираюсь для каждой категории товара в базе создавать новую таблицу. Насколько это плохо или хорошо? Что будет если категорий будет тысяча или несколько тысяч ?

Comment: ничего плохого в этом нет

Comment: У вас у каждой категории свой набор свойств товара? И они (свойства) сильно отличаются в разных категориях?

Comment: Да, я сначала пытался создать таблицу с свойствами точнее с что-то типо моделей свойств, соединить её с таблицей свойств и потом всё это просто прикручивать к таблицу с категориями. Но возникли проблемы с тем что разные свойства требуют разный формат и длину ячеек и вообще требует сложной связи между собой

Comment: Предположу, что реляционные БД в принципе не подходят для описываемой задачи

Comment: Гляньте в гугл https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0+%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86+%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F+%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B0+%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2+%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Comment: Даже если разные свойства имеют разный формат и разную длину, то реляционные базы можно использовать. Если создать таблицу свойств, то в ней может быть 1020 столбца суммарным размером от 0 до 65535 байт. То есть, если в таблице будет 1000 колонок из них для каждой строки будет заполнено 10-20 колонок, и размер данных не превысит 64 КБайт, то всё уложится в одну таблицу. И сделать таблицу категорий с колонками - номер, название, описание свойств. Описание свойств - json или xml, задающий соответствие между названиями свойств и колонками в таблице свойств.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы будете потом страдать от большого числа таблиц. Предлагаю организовать данные в БД в виде дерева. Так как вы пока не знаете число категорий, а они будут только расти. С иерархическими таблицами, запросами вы можете ознакомиться [здесь](http://habrahabr.ru/post/43955/).